# Changing User Profile Property for all the users in sharepoint 2010 using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I want to change the edit setting and Display setting  value of a user profile property called Department  for all users. Can someone please tell me how to do it.

I can get to the department property with this powershell. Right now this Property Edit Setting is DO not Allow Users to edit this property and I want to make it Editable for every user.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$mySiteUrl = "http://www.test.com/mysite"
$site = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$userProfile = $profileManager.GetUserProfile("Test\822");
$userProfile.Properties | sort DisplayName | FT DisplayName,Name,@{Label="Type";Expression={$_.CoreProperty.Type}}
$userProfile["Department"].Value 
$site.Dispose()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean this property, right?

[image]

The following script demonstrates how to set `IsUserEditable` sub property of `Departments` user profile property:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}


$siteUrl = "http://contoso.intranet.com/"

$site = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext($site)


$profileConfigMgr = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager($context) 
$profilePropMgr = $profileConfigMgr.ProfilePropertyManager
$subtypePropMgr = $profilePropMgr.GetProfileSubtypeProperties("UserProfile")
$subtypeProp = $subtypePropMgr.GetPropertyByName("Department")
$subtypeProp.IsUserEditable = $true
$subtypeProp.Commit()
```

**References**

[How to: Work with user profiles and organization profiles by using the server object model in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163142.aspx)